# How to clean up my JSON response before writing to file in python/django?

Tags: json, django, python-2.7

This where the fucntion converts dictionary to json for a HttpResponse -

```
HttpResponse(
    json.dumps(cm_dict),
    content_type='application/javascript; charset=utf8'
)
```

I understand that since content type is set, the json response is displayed pretty. But I what want to do is write the the json to a file and come in a somewhat similar format.

What i get is this -

```
"{\"a\" : \"b\", \"c\" : \"d\"}"
```

that is written into file using the below -

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(json_data, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4,ensure_ascii=False)
```

what i want is -

```
{
  "a": "b",
  "c": "d"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the contents of `json_data` is already JSON. There is no need to dump it to JSON again; just write the string.